# Random Forest with more features than data points

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, random-forest, tf-idf

I am trying to predict whether a particular service ticket raised by client needs a code change.

I have training data.

I have around 17k data points with problem description and tag (Y for code change required and N for no code change)

I did TF-IDF and it gave me 27k features. So I tried to fit RandomForestClassifier (sklearn python) with this 17k x 27k matrix.

I am getting very low scores on test set while training accuracy is very high.

Precision on train set: **89%**
Precision on test set: **21%**

Can someone suggest any workarounds?

I am using this model now:

```
sklearn.RandomForestClassifier(n_jobs=3,n_estimators=100,class_weight='balanced',max_features=None,oob_score=True)
```

Please help!

**EDIT:**
I have 11k training data with 900 positives (skewed). I tried LinearSVC sparsify but didn't work as well as Truncated SVD (Latent Semantic Indexing). maxFeatures=None performs better on the test set than without it.

I have also tried SVM, logistic (l2 and l1), ExtraTrees. RandonForest still is working best.
Right now, going at 92% precision on positives but recall is 3% only

Any other suggestions would be appreciated!

**Update:**
Feature engineering helped a lot. I pulled features out of the air (len of chars, len of words, their, difference, ratio, day of week the problem was of reported, day of month, etc) and now I am at 19-20% recall with >95% accuracy.

Food for your thoughts on using word2vec average vectors as deep features for the free text instead of tf-idf or bag of words ???

Comment: First suggestion is to never optimise to a test set, this is a recipe for disaster. For parameter optimisation you should always use a validation set of some form, i.e. cross-validation using the training set only to chose parameters, retrain on the entire training set and then test on the test set.

Comment: thanks @ncfirth ! I split it like u said and I was able to detect that using ngrams_range(1,2) was giving me better results than before... my precision has gone up (>95%) but I am still stuck at a recall of 3%. I need at least 12-15%. I have tried to play with prob thresholds but they take a hit on precision (on recall >10%, precision <35%). Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Have you tried using recall as the scoring method in the cross-validation? Choosing parameters to increase recall might help out.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Seems like you've overfit on your training set. Basically the model has learnt noise on the data rather than the signal. There are a few ways to combat this, but it seems fairly obvious that you're model has overfit because of the incredibly large number of features you're feeding it.</strike>

**EDIT:**
It seems I was perhaps too quick to jump to the conclusion of overfitting, however this may still be the case (left as an exercise to the reader!). However feature selection may still improve the generalisability and reliability of your model.

A good place to start for removing features in `scikit-learn` would be [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html). Using sparsity is a fairly common way to perform feature selection:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
import numpy as np

# Create some data
X = np.random.random((1800, 2700))
# Boolean labels as the y vector
y = np.random.random(1800)
y = y > 0.5
y = y.astype(bool)

lsvc = LinearSVC(C=0.05, penalty="l1", dual=False).fit(X, y)
model = SelectFromModel(lsvc, prefit=True)
X_new = model.transform(X)

print X_new.shape
```

Which returns a new matrix of shape `(1800, 640)`. You can tune the number of features selected by altering the `C` parameter (called the penalty parameter in `scikit-learn` but sometimes called the sparsity parameter).

Comment: this is good stuff I didn't know this before. Thanks, but still not much of an improvement. I tried Truncated SVD and the results were much better. I will try to edit the question now to give you more info.

Answer (score 1):

**[edited]**

Random forest handles more features than data points quite fine. RF is e.g. used for micro-array studies with e.g. a 100:5000 data point/feature ratio or in single-nucleotide_polymorphism(SNP) studies with e.g 5000:500,000 ratio.

I do disagree with the *diagnose* provided by @ncfirth, but the suggested *treatment* of variable selection may help anyway.

Your default random forest is not badly overfitted. It is just not meaningful to pay any attention to a non-cross validated training set prediction performance for a RF model, because any sample will end in the terminal nodes/leafs it has itself defined. But the overall ensemble model is still robust.
**[edit]** If you would change the `max_depth` or `min_samples_split`, the training precision would probably drop, but that is not the point. The non-cross validated training error/precision of a random forest model or many other ensemble models simply does not estimate anything useful.

**[I did before edit confuse max_features with n_estimators, sry I mostly use R]**

Setting max_features="none" is not random forest, but rather 'bagged trees'. You may benefit from a somewhat lower max_features which improve regularization and speed, maybe not. I would try lowering max_features to somewhere between 27000/3 and sqrt(27000), the typical optimal range.

You may achieve better test set prediction performance by feature selection. You can run one RF model, keep the top ~5-50% most ***important*** features and then re-run the model with fewer features. "*L1 lasso*" variable selection as ncfirth suggests may also be a viable solution.

Your metric of prediction performance, *precision*, may not be optimal in case unbalanced data or if the cost of false-negative and false-positive is quite different.

If your test set is still predicted much worse than the out-of-bag cross-validated training set, you may have problems with your [I.I.D. assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) that any supervised ML model rely on or you may need to wrap the entire data processing in an outer cross-validation loop, to avoid over optimistic estimation of prediction performance due to e.g. the variable selection step.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing, "any sample will end in the terminal nodes/leafs it has itself defined" is an example of overfitting to training data. Also one can use statistics from non-cross validated random forests if one considers `min_samples_split` and `max_depth` (using `sklearn` parameter names). For example if `max_depth=4` then your statement about terminal nodes will not hold.

Comment: *"Basically the model has learnt noise on the data rather than the signal."* -I would say not necessarily. Training set prediction performance does not reveal if the random forest ensemble is over fitted or not. RF is a special variant of bagging, and the individual learners in a bagging ensemble are usually quite unstable (high variance/low bias). That is in fact a major advantage of bagging ensembles, not a problem. See edit regarding `max_depth` and `min_samples_split`.

Comment: My intuition when I see that many features and a big drop in accuracy on the test set is over fitting. I would suggest that using `max_features="none"` increases the risk of over fitting in this case, as finding the best split may indeed lead to learning noise. Unfortunately we will never know without the data though! +1 for a well explained answer.